# css border styling

Tags: css

On one of my wordpress sites, there is a wrapper which has `border: 1px solid #cccccc`.
I'm using a child theme, and only want the wrapper to have the left and right borders, not the top and bottom.
I know I can use border-left etc, but it will still have a full border because the parent theme is specifying the border as above.
How can I get it the way I want WITHOUT changing the parent css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do something like this and add a border-width:

```
#box {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
}
```

This could be declared in the child to override the parent.

Comment: I did something simlar to this in that I used: 
`border: 0px;
border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
border-right: 1px solid #cccccc;`.  That way, my 0px overrides the parent css' 1px and then I just declare the border I do want...  Is this this OK?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of answers to that.

CSS is processed in order of the CSS file being loaded, so if the child theme is loaded after the parent theme, then the child theme should win.

If that's not what's happening, there's a CSS attribute !important which puts the CSS style to the top of the queue.  These are still processed in order, so conflicting !important attributes, are evaluated in the same order as the load.

all you should have to do, if the css is being loaded out of order is change the attribute in your child theme to:

```
border-width: 0 1px !important;
```